# Code generated by storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I tried to create a label in code, in my appdelegate implementation after finish launching with options.

(in the FinishedLaunchingWithOptions method)

However that did not work, nothing showed up even though i added it to the window.

So i went to the storyboard and created a label, my question is, is this storyboard generating any code for me to edit??? If so, where is it, if not, whats the point then? how do i add functionality to the stuff i create on the storyboards, thanks

Comment: If you actually want to see the storyboard code right click -> open as -> source code. I have actually had to look through it once to find error I was having a really had time tracking down.

Comment: I think what you want is modifying the label you created in the storyboard. You do this via creating an IBOutlet of that label. After that you are able to access the label from within your code. This is really very basic and honestly I think you should watch/read (I prefer the former ;)) some basic tutorials which will teach you the very basics and more.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a tutorial from a website where several tutorials have helped me.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

The short answer is that using the storyboard does generate code, just that you don't see it (you can actually look at the code from the storyboard but I doubt it will make any sense at this point). Essentially to make the UILabels and texts fields work you have to hook them up as outlets in the headers for your view Controllers. I would suggest checking out the tutorial or another like it. The Big Nerd Ranch Guide to IOS was also a good resource for me when I was started out as well as objective-c for dummies.